# OS X Mojave (10.14) patch

Tags: macos, imac, mojave

I'm trying to install macOS Mojave beta from the app store.
I have a 2009 iMac (iMac9,1) and apple has giving me an error when trying to download it from the App Store:

> macOS Mojave cannot be on this Mac.

I am familiar with [macOS High Sierra Patcher](http://dosdude1.com/highsierra).  It successfully patched my Mac without any problems.  Since Mojave is so new, there has not been a patch released for that version.  I was wondering if there was a way to manually patch it and get the file since the App Store won't let me download it.

Comment: You will need a patch that is compatible with Mojave - did you contact the developer of the patch?